# Is there a more efficient way to wrap a float?

Tags: c++, performance, math, while-loop, floating-point

I've been looking for examples on how to wrap a float between two numbers, similar to how you can do with integers using modulus. Examples I've found either involve using fmod to just find the remainder past the decimal point, assuming it's for a circle and doing pi-based math, among other things that didn't quite do what I needed. Finally, I just wrote this:

```
float fwrap(float x, float a0, float a1)
{
    float mx = max(a0, a1);
    float mn = min(a0, a1);
    float nw = x;

    while(nw < mn) nw += mx - mn;
    while(nw > mx) nw -= mx - mn;
};
```

It works, but I'm sure if the original value is too far from the range, it'll slow thinks down, so is there a faster way to do this that doesn't involve loops?

All I need it to do is to wrap a number around a range when it goes beyond them, for instance, if `a0` is 10 and `a1` is 20, then if `x` is 25, it should return 15, but it should also work with floats, so if `x` is 8.5, it should return 18.5.

Comment: A faster way to do it without loops is to use `fmod()`.

Comment: "that didn't quite do what I needed", you should describe what you do need.

Comment: I've tried using `fmod()`, but it only seems to return the stuff after the decimal point, at least going by my tests. Do you have an example of how to use it in this case?

Comment: As for what I need, I need it to basically make it so that when a float goes beyond a certain range, it wraps around to the other side, for instance, if a sprite goes off screen, have it come back around to the other side.

Comment: Your code will stall for `a0==a1`, or for `a0=1; a1=1.001; x=1e20`. Do you want results "as-if" calculated with infinite precision? Or something which generally works for sane input values?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with `a0 + fmod(x, a1 - a0)` in the general case.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to work from precise specifications for what your function needs to do, rather than vague descriptions like "similar to [something]". Define what you want, and the implementation might almost write itself.

Comment: I can't always ensure a0 < a1 since the values may be entered by a user. As for precise specifications, I don't know how I can be more precise than I want to make a number stay within a range and wrap around when it goes beyond those boundaries.

Anyway, I found a solution, but because I can't think of a more precise way to word my question, I can't get it unlocked so I can show the answer I came up with, and I can't delete it, so, yeah, what do I do now?

Comment: The clearest way to express what your function should do might be to write a set of unit tests for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a more efficient way to wrap a float?

Use `std::fmod()`.

```
#include <cmath>

float fwrap(float x, float min, float max) {
    if (min > max) {
        return fwrap(x, max, min);
    }
    return (x >= 0 ? min : max) + std::fmod(x, max - min);
}
```

You could even make it generic, to work with other floating-point types:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>

template<std::floating_point F>
F fwrap(F x, F min, F max) {
    if (min > max) {
        std::swap(min, max);  // alternative to recursion
    }
    return (x < 0 ? max : min) + std::fmod(x, max - min);
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I needed. It works well enough for positive numbers, however, when x is negative, it breaks. I had to check the sign and use `return a1 + fmod(x, diff);` if x was negative.

Comment: @KelvinShadewing You can edit this answer to include that finding.

Comment: Somehow, I didn't notice you can edit other people's answers. XD Thanks.

Comment: @KelvinShadewing There is no `mn` nor `mx` defined...

Comment: @KelvinShadewing community wiki answers are meant for anyone to _carefully_ edit.  And with higher rep, you can edit other's Q & A.